# Deferred expression in Visual Studio macros

Tags: c++, macros, deferred

I tried examples from this [page](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms#deferred-expression) in Visual Studio 2017 (Windows Console Application). And this code doesn't work as expected:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define EMPTY()
#define DEFER(id) id EMPTY()

#define A() 123

int main() {
    cout << DEFER(A)() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code outputs 123 on the console, so DEFER(A)() expands to 123. For instance, in CLion (cygwin 2.9.0) the code works according example from the page, DEFER(A)() expands to A() and causes an error.

So, do Visual Studio macros have some significant differences from others and how to make deferred expressions in Visual Studio in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Probably related [MSVC Preprocessor Progress towards Conformance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/07/06/msvc-preprocessor-progress-towards-conformance/)